# why can the cin.get() function strip the '\n' in a string?

Tags: c++

According to my teacher's course, the difference between the cin.get() and cin.getline() is that , when you ask them to stop fetching when meeting the special character you've set , the former one would stop right before the character, while the later one would stop right behind the special character.( I know the default character of the two is '\n', which means return.)

but then why can the cin.get() function strip the '\n' in a string?

my code looks like this:

```
int main()
{
       char a[10][10];
       int n=0;
       cin>>n;

      for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
        cin.getline(a[i],10);
      for (int i=0; i<n ;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
}
```

with the code like this, when I enter 7 for n, I can only use it for six time.( For example, if I want to enter Sunday, Monday,...,saturday, I can not enter the last one Saturday.)  The result looks like this:
[image: see? I can't not enter the 'Saturday']

But if I add one line of code , which is

```
cin.get();
```

and make it like this:

```
int main()
{
       char a[10][10];
       int n=0;
       cin>>n;
       cin.get()
      for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
        cin.getline(a[i],10);
      for (int i=0; i<n ;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
}
```

I can use the code for seven times when I enter 7 for n ( which mean that I can enter the Saturday at the seventh time) .

why is that?  (The result looks like this:)[image: I can enter my 'Saturday' now]

the result looks like this:

***I mean, I firstly enter 7, and then I enter Sunday, Monday,..., Saturday..***

Comment: Your teacher must be talking about overload #4 of `get()` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get), which reads up to a delimiter, while you're using overload #1 which reads a single character even if it's a newline.

Comment: @interjay Can you elaborate the difference ?

Answer (score 1):

cin reads the 7, and then getline() reads the newline and treats it like a blank line, and your program correctly outputs the blank line.  Number your output lines to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't "strip" anything!
It reads the newline that you entered into your console immediately after typing the number `7`.

It prevents the first `getline` call from being a waste and resulting in an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you already know the answer: `cin.get()` consumes the residual new line ('\n') character left over from the `cin>>n;`.

When you don't call `cin.get()`, the residual new line will be read and an empty string is returned for the first `cin.getline(a[i],10)`, then 6 lines with values.